# Clearing DataTable while editing DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatable

I've got a DataTable bound to a WPF (.NET 3.5, WPFToolkit.dll) DataGrid. This is inside a very large client-server application. The server can asynchronously send data to the client "engine"; this data is sent in the form of properties which are set onto my control by the engine.

So, as an example of what I mean, I have a `class MyFunkyDataGrid : DataGrid`. `MyFunkyDataGrid` has a DependencyProperty called `MyFunkyData` which is of type `Dictionary<string, Object>`. Whenever `MyFunkyData` is changed on the server, it is immediately synchronized on the client, and set onto `MyFunkyDataGrid`. When `MyFunkyData` changes, I rip through the dictionary and set the data onto my grid's DataTable.

Of course, when this happens, I first need to **clear** the DataTable of its current data. So I call `dataTable.Clear()`. Normally this works a treat. **BUT** if I am currently editing a cell in MyFunkyDataGrid when the dataTable is cleared I get:

```
System.ExecutionEngineException was unhandled
  Message=Exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' was thrown.
  InnerException:
```

which crashes my app. I've tried calling `CancelEdit()` on MyFunkyDataGrid, I've tried calling it on the DataRow itself. I've tried calling `RejectChanges()` on the DataTable before I call `Clear()`. No dice.

Has anyone ever seen something like this before?

Comment: What happens if you set the `ItemsSource` or `DataContext` of `MyFunkyGrid` to `null`?

Comment: @SeToY No data gets displayed (as expected). The underlying dataTable is changing, but no crashes happen. This only seems to happen when the ItemSource is bound to DataTable.DefaultView and I'm editing a cell while clearing the dataTable.

Comment: Does this happen if the number of items in the ItemsSource is size 37?

Comment: So you want to just discard any edits?  I would try setting the focus to another control.  And why are you clearing a datatable and starting fresh?  Why not just revise/insert/delete the appropriate rows?   Why not bind to Object of Dic(string,Object).   DataTable has a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why exception is getting thrown even if datagrid.CancelEdit() is called before clearing datatable. But two more precautions can be taken before clearing datagrid which may avoid the exception:

(1)You can set selecteditem to null of datagrid

(2)You can set ItemSource of datagrid to null instead of datatable and then clearing datatable.